# Is there any way to add Tags to the slide from Power Point web add-in?

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-addins

We know we can add the Tags attributes to the slide from "windows PowerPoint add-in". But we couldn't find that option in web add-in.  Is there any way to add the TAGS to the presentation from the PowerPoint web add-in? We are stuck with this issue. Any help would be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't currently a way to do that with a PowerPoint web add-in. But it's a good idea. Please suggest it to [Microsoft Developer Platform](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform)

Comment: Is there any way to embed an attribute in the slide from web add-in? Also, we need to read it from the web add-in.

Comment: No, but perhaps you could have a small invisible text area (font color is the same as background color) that holds the data.

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve a specific text box from a slide?